# How to use choices in a model from a table previously populated with a fixture

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
```

I populate the model via `python manage.py loaddata db.json` (JSON fixture)

After the model is populated, I would like to use those regions and countries as 'options' for another model field

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(#when creating a new project: default - active
        max_length=250, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        default=PROJECT_STATUS_DEFAULT,
        choices=PROJECT_STATUS,
    )
    region = models.CharField(
        max_length=250, 
        null=False, 
        blank=False, 
        default=, #I would like to use here the options available in the Countries model
        choices=, #I would like to use here the options available in the Countries model
    )
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=250, 
        null=False, 
        blank=False,
        default=, #I would like to use here the options available in the Countries model
        choices=  #I would like to use here the options available in the Countries model
    )
```

I did some research and it is clear to me how to use choices from a `constants.py` file, but I have not found a good explanation
on how to use it with previous populated models.

Comment: Use a ForeignKey from Project to Countries instead. You can just link to the already created data

Comment: Sounds promising, could you provide an example?

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Countries` already contains your data, use a `models.ForeignKey` from `Project` to `Countries` so that you can just select an existing entry.

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.region} - {self.country}'


class Project(models.Model):
    project_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(#when creating a new project: default - active
        max_length=250, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True, 
        default=PROJECT_STATUS_DEFAULT,
        choices=PROJECT_STATUS,
    )
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

The `__str__` method of `Countries` is what is used as the label for the select form field dropdown by default

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how about region under the Project model?

In other words, how can I tell to the model Project that country = country column from Countries model and region = region column from Countries model?

Comment: @Cheknov you shouldn't need separate columns on the `Project` model, you can access the two values by following the ForeignKey: `my_project.country.region` and  `my_project.country. country`. It's possible to create things like properties if you want to access the values in the way you suggest but not necessary